# most efficient way to query across tables / models in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, being User and Absence, in a Rail 3.2 ruby 2.1.5 app

```
class User
  has_many :absences
end

class Absence
  belongs_to :user
end
```

on the Absence there is a :start_date and an :end_date

I need to figure out the following in the most efficient way

"how many users are absent today?"

So this will be a count of the distinct user ids from a selection of all the absences where the start date is today or before today and the end date is today or after today.

I thought about doing something like

```
user_ids =  Absence.where("absences.start_date <= ? and absences.end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today).map(&:user_id)
user_ids.uniq!
user_ids.count
```

That "think" that gets me the count of the IDs I need, but is the most efficient way to do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
absent_users = User.includes(:absences).where("absences.start_date <= ? and absences.end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
```

or to be more concise:

```
current_date = Date.today
absent_users = User.includes(:absences).where("absences.start_date <= ? and absences.end_date >= ?", current_date, current_date)
```

It should get you distinct results of user, if you still don't get distinct results then add [`distinct`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) in the active record chain.

Are you after just the unique `user_id` records? then you can just add [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) in your query for `user_id` column:

```
absent_user_ids = Absence.select(:user_id).where("absences.start_date <= ? and absences.end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today).distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
Absence.where("absences.start_date <= ? and absences.end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today).group("user_id").length
```